# How to convert KML file to KMZ file in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, kml, kmz

I have created successfully `kml` file called `gis.kml`,Now i had seen a marginal size change when you convert KML to KMZ by using `googleearth`.So i am thinking how to convert `KML` to `KMZ` in c#.I have code to convert any file to .zip ,but that will not work here

Comment: Peter : See following webpage :https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmzarchives

Comment: That mean ZIP utility is sufficient?I created kmz file by using googleearth from kml and zip file by using 7zip and found some KB size difference.Hence thought it would be different.But the link you sent mentions both same

Comment: Just make sure any files referenced in kml are in correct location in kmz.  The description says kmz must have one folder (which could be empty).

Comment: @jdweng Thats great

Comment: @jdweng regarding the question which i asked two days before, can you maintain same namespace herirchy on top and remove further instances??

Comment: I didn't fix issue because I wasn't sure it was a problem.  Try following change.  Not exactly the same as original code. From : kml.RemoveAll(); To : kml.Element(ns + "Folder").Remove();

Answer (score 2):

You can either read in the file 'gis.kml' and add its contents to a KMZ file or you can programmatically create the KML elements and convert to a byte array to write to the KMZ stream. This solution uses the [CSharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/) to create the KMZ file.

Here's snippet of C# code to create a KMZ file:

```
using (FileStream fileStream = File.Create(ZipFilePath)) // Zip File Path (String Type)
{
    using (ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(fileStream))
    {
        // following line must be present for KMZ file to work in Google Earth
        zipOutputStream.UseZip64 = UseZip64.Off;

        // now normally create the zip file as you normally would 
        // add root KML as first entry
        ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry("doc.kml");
        zipOutputStream.PutNextEntry(zipEntry);  
        //build you binary array from FileSystem or from memory... 
        zipOutputStream.write(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("gis.kml")); 
        zipOutputStream.CloseEntry();
        // next add referenced file entries (e.g. icons, etc.)
        // ...
        //don't forget to clean your resources and finish the outputStream
        zipOutputStream.Finish();
        zipOutputStream.Close();
    }
}
```

Can also create the KMZ file using the [ZipArchive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

Answer (score 0):

[KMZ to KML](http://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmzarchives)

Zip the file then change the extension to KMZ